# Finding Up-to-Date React Course Slides

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Is there any good React course slides for a presentation?

I searched for any, but a lot of them are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

better to create your own. Taking help of documentation will be helpful. React Docs are real good.

Comment: i am willing to do that but i need one asap for a bootcamp tomorrow i found some but they got a lot of missing infos and outdated practices !

Comment: unusual recommendation: use ChatGPT for creating slide content.